# Graphical bug during the logging after installing Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, graphics, bug, mojave

I recently installed Mojave on my MacBook Pro 2017, and I encounter a graphical bug which is, if not hindering, still annoying.
When I boot the Mac and enter my password at the login screen, the usual white bar appears underneath my avatar and keeps on charging until approximately the middle, where the charging becomes slower and suddenly the screen turns black, and then appears just the Apple logo and the white bar underneath, filled up to the same point as before the screen turning black, which finishes charging and I arrive directly on my Desktop from this screen.
I already tried to clean my PRAM, the SCM and I've done a reinstall of Mojave (while conserving my files), so I'm really wondering whether this is something hardware related or just some random Mojave bug.
Some details (which might be related to the case or not) :
- On the login screen, my avatar seems to be a little bit blurry and I have the Mojave dune as a background picture, which is no more the case when I close the session and open it once again (I mean, I just have my wallpaper and my avatar isn't blurry in this case).
- When I shutdown the Mac, sometimes the Desktop becomes a little bit gray and freezes before the Mac shutdowns.
- During my first install of Mojave, the iCloud configuration failed and since the small gear kept on turning for hours, I had to manually reboot the Mac (but this should have been repaired with a clean install, I guess ?)
Any help would be appreciated !

EDIT: It turned out that this strange logo appearing during the boot WAS a random Mojave bug - when I updated the system, it disappeared. It was just disappointing that their support couldn't tell me this clearly and instead tried to make me reinstall my system several times...

Comment: sounds like the graphic mode is switching. do you have graphics card installed ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Since it's a Macbook Pro, I didn't install anything - it should just be the integrated GPU Intel Iris Pro Graphics 640. How should I check that and what should I do in this cas?

Comment: I checked in the preferences, and I confirm that I cannot even switch the graphics card, so it should be integrated to the CPU. Can it be something other?

Comment: First create new user account and log in with that to see if the problem goes away. If not lets fix your hard drive.

Comment: I tried to create a new user and login, it didn't change anything - I still got the Apple logo during the loading of the new session. What should I try next?

Comment: can you take a pic of that problem (with your phone for example)

Comment: I've taken a small video of what's happening between the moment I enter my password and the moment when the desktop appears, the link is : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7k2qn3jk1n4m74r/AACj2243w7eXJqMwSWnlkPYCa?dl=0